# Resizing visual area of ccscren object in OSX

Tags: macos, cocos2d-iphone, ccscene

I have created a fairly simple graphics program by starting with the PeevedPenguin project using iPad as target and then trying to retarget it to the Mac.  I am using current versions of Spritebuilder, Cocos, and Xcode.

When I move over to the Mac target, the game moves over with a number of smaller issues but I am having one big issue with how to expand the visual area of the scene.  It always loads in a small visual window that cuts off display of any activity outside that box.  My scene is basicially a derivation of the background screen from PeevedPenguins.

For this application I want the scene to fill, but not expand past, a window the size of my screen.

I have googled about every possible idea on finding a tutorial concerning how to build these windows, but unfortunately, some other use of the term windows fills up my search results.

Would really appreciated help in solving this issue.  Even a link to some sort of "Graphic design for windows on the Mac" would help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apple provides a convenient ["Implementing the Full-Screen Experience"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/MOSXAppProgrammingGuide/FullScreenApp/FullScreenApp.html) section in their Mac App Programming Guide.